# I can get access to object's properties if method is called from anonymous function, but I can't do it if method is called directly. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

$.Comment = function() {
      this.alertme = "Alert!";
    }

```
$.Comment.prototype.send = function() {

  var self = this;
  $.post(
    self.url,
    {
      'somedata' : self.somedata
    },
    function(data) {          //using anonymous function to call object's method
      self.callback(data);
    } 
  );

}

$.Comment.prototype.callback = function(data) {
  alert(this.alertme);
}
```

This code works great when I'm calling `$.Comment.send()`, but this code won't work...

```
$.Comment.prototype.send = function() {

  var self = this;
  $.post(
    self.url,
    {
      'somedata' : self.somedata
    },
    self.callback          //using direct access to method
  );

}
```

Please, could you explain me why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time, self.callback passes the reference to the function $.Comment.prototype.callback. As with all Javascript functions, this doesn't carry a binding to the same "this" object (the same reason why you are storing `this` and using `self` above, but you are using it overzealously).

Basically, if a function is used within a different context, `this` no longer refers to the same thing. The first instance above, you store `this` as `self`, and then invoke `self.callback()`. This invokes `callback` with `self` as its `this` object. The second instance simply passes `callback` the function (without context) to be called. When it is called then, `this` is lost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for my English, but what do you mean saying "but you are using it overzealously"? Other part of your answer is clear for me, thank you!

Comment: Sorry. Basically you're using `self` where `this` is still valid. this is only invalid when you're passing a function to another function to be invoked there. If you're in the current function, `this` is still valid.